# 正規表現で"<h2>〜","<h2>〜"と抜き出すには。

Tags: php, 正規表現

正規表現で苦戦しております。

```
'<h2>foo</h2>
    randomstr
    <span>randamstr</span>
<h2>bar</h2>
    <div>randomstr</div>
<h2>baz</h2>
    randomstr'
```

このような文字列を

```
[
    [0] => '<h2>foo</h2>randomstr<span>randamstr</span>',
    [1] => '<h2>bar</h2><div>randomstr</div>',
    [2] => '<h2>baz</h2>randomstr',
]
```

このようにpreg_match_allなどで抜き出したいのですが、どのように正規表現を書けばよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まずは`"<h2>〜"`の`〜`が何を表すのかきちんと定義してください。

ここでは、

- 直近の`<h2>`の手前まで

または(`<h2>`がもう存在しなければ)

- 文字列の末尾まで

を表すものとしておきます。

PHPの現在の標準正規表現エンジンであるPCREでは、

「直近の」→非貪欲な量指定子`*?`
「…の手前」→[assertion](http://php.net/manual/ja/regexp.reference.assertions.php)(バッファを消費しないマッチング)

が使えます(最近の正規表現実装なら大抵使えるはず)ので、比較的自然に正規表現パターンとして表現することができます。

```
$pattern = '/<h2>.*?(?=<h2>|$)/s';
```

---

(実行例)

```
$html = '<h2>foo</h2>
    randomstr
    <span>randamstr</span>
<h2>bar</h2>
    <div>randomstr</div>
<h2>baz</h2>
    randomstr';
$pattern = '/<h2>.*?(?=<h2>|$)/s';
$matches = [];
if( preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches) ) {
  var_dump($matches);
}
```

出力:

> ```
> array(1) {
>   [0]=>
>   array(3) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(54) "<h2>foo</h2>
>     randomstr
>     <span>randamstr</span>
> "
>     [1]=>
>     string(38) "<h2>bar</h2>
>     <div>randomstr</div>
> "
>     [2]=>
>     string(26) "<h2>baz</h2>
>     randomstr"
>   }
> }
> ```

Macに乗っているのは古いPHP 5.6ですが、PCRE周りの仕様は変更されていないので、PHP 7, 7.1でも同じ結果が得られるはずです。なお、最初の仮定があなたの必要とされる動作と異なる場合には、ご質問内容を編集して要件をより明確化するようにしてください。

Comment: 私が仮定していた結果そのとおりでした。
ご回答ありがとうございます。